# Migration from JBoss 5.1 EAP to Wildfly 10

Tags: java, web-services, wildfly, jboss5.x

We are looking to migrate existing applications on JBoss EAP 5.1 to Wildfly 10. 
Please let me know if anyone has already done this migration and is there is any risks involved.
I have two instances of JBoss 5.1 running currently in two different VMs. One housing a webapplication and another enterprise application.
 - I have doubts around if WildFly 10 being community edition, is it good to move from JBoss 5.1 EAP to Wildfly10?

Comment: Not really a question for suited for SO.  Too broad.  Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

The below is the migration guide:

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en/red-hat-jboss-enterprise-application-platform/7.0/single/migration-guide/